# Convert .DAT file to CSV with Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I'm Using Talend 5.2.2 and I want to convert a DAT file to a CSV in order to split date in each row.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really simple to do this in talend:

```
tFileInputPositional -->  tMap / tJavaRow --> tFileOutputDelimited
```

You could use a tlogrow for debugging between the input and output.

Comment: Another solution : tFileInputFullRow --> tMap --> tFileOutputDelimited

Comment: Thats what I said. But you can use tJavaRow as well for the split, it depends what you prefer. Since I like java, I usually go with the tJavaRow.